# Get-Process Does Not Work Within a Class [PowerShell]

Tags: macos, powershell, class

I am trying to get running processes in a function within a class but it does nothing. Looks like the compiler ignores it, however, outside of the class it works perfectly.

```
<# Works here #>
#Get-Process

class Test
{
    [void]TestFunction()
    {
        <# DOES NOT WORK HERE #>
        Get-Process
    }
}

[Test]$object = [Test]::new()
$object.TestFunction()


<# Works here #>
#Get-Process
```

P.S. I am using PowerShell on macOS with VS Code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does nothing, because you said to do nothing.

```
[void]TestFunction()
```

1. `void` instructs to suppress any output object.
2. no return statement is defined within method.

Here is working example:

```
class Test
{
    [System.Diagnostics.Process[]]TestFunction()
    {
        return Get-Process
    }
}
```

and no need to store results in intermediate variable.

Answer (score 3):

This happens, as [classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7) work different a way from ordinary Powershell.

> In class methods, no objects get sent to the pipeline except those
>   mentioned in the return statement.

Thus, one needs a member variable that stores function result. Output can be then accessed via member, or, say, printed with `write-host`.

```
class Test
{
    $p =@()
    TestFunction()
    {
        $this.p=Get-Process # or get-process|write-host
    }
}

[Test]$object = [Test]::new()
$object.TestFunction()

$object.p
# Prints process list
```